# Is there a way to create generic Action or Func

Tags: c#, generics

Can I do something like this:

```
Action<T> mapComponentFields<T> = (T arg) =>
    {
        // TODO
    };

int arg = 10;
mapComponentFields<int>(arg)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not like that - but you *can* write a generic method which would return a delegate:

```
static Action<T> MapField<T>()
{
    // This will use Console.WriteLine(object) of course...
    return arg => Console.WriteLine(arg);
}

...

MapField<int>()(10);
```

As another example, you could create a method to return an identity function:

```
static Func<T, T> Identity<T>()
{
    return value => value;
}
```

But any time this is called, there has to be a concrete type *at execution time*. So you can call it from a generic type where a type parameter is already defined:

```
public class Sample<TFoo>
{
    static void Test()
    {
        Func<TFoo, TFoo> identity = Helpers.Identity<TFoo>();
    }
}
```

... but you can't just declare a type parameter *within* a method as you appear to be trying to do in your question.